# What's the function of "@" in regular expressions on PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have seen some examples about regular expressions with "@" on PHP, something like this:

```
preg_match ("@[a-zA-Z0-9]@i", $value, $occurrences);
```

I could see that this counts the number of matches of regular expression which were found in the `$value` variable, but I would like to be sure if the "@" is used for this specific case or what's the main function of "@" in regular expressions?.

Can you help me please?

Comment: that present `@` is only a delimiter. It could have been `#` or `/` if that's what the question is about. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Delimiter secrets http://stackoverflow.com/a/37058367/557597

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [custom delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the regular expression pattern. The most common is `/`, in your case they were changed to `@`.

The benefit of custom delimiters has to do with escaping. This is best shown by example.

Consider:

```
preg_match ("/Some\/Path/i", $value, $occurrences);
```

Versus:

```
preg_match ("#Some/Path#i", $value, $occurrences);
```

However, on a personal note, I tend to avoid them as it makes the regular expression pattern, well, *customized*. Just use the standard `/` delimiters.

Comment: Using a metacharacter as a delimiters is a problem, you should mention that.

Comment: the option requiring less escapes might end up being more portable though eh? in c#, for example, the # delimited regex with no escaped / would be the valid one.

Comment: Delimiters are a PCRE thing, and you can use whatever you want for them in anything that implements PCRE. The only "portability" problem is moving the regex to not-PCRE where it still doesn't matter what the delimiter is because you have to remove them altogether.

Comment: @Jason McCreary thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Sammitch. I have updated my note.